# PDF Reference Manual of an old version of R Package

Tags: r, package, version

I want to get pdf Reference Manual of an old version of R package. Specifically I want to get pdf Reference Manual of VetResearchLMM version 0.1.0.

Comment: If the package was on CRAN, MS (which bought revolution analytics) keeps a (roughly daily) repository of CRAN. Here is the link for march 14, 2016. https://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/snapshot/2016-03-14/

Comment: Thanks @Imo  (+1) for very useful comment. Would appreciate if you change your comment to answer for future users. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For packages that are on CRAN, you should be a ble to use the MS CRAN archive, which is roughly updated daily.

As an example, 
https://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/snapshot/2016-03-14/

is the archive for March 14, 2014.

By clicking on the "packages > Table of available packages, sorted by name", you can access the pages of packages that were available on that date, including the reference manual (if it was posted).